# static::$model::$table - how to achieve this?

Tags: php, static

#### Situation

Consider I've got the following class structure:

```
// a user model
class UserModel extends BaseModel {
    protected static $table = 'Users';
}

// a controller for the user model 
class UserModelController extends BaseModelController {
    protected static $model = 'UserModel';
}

// a base model
class BaseModel {
    protected static $table = '';
}

// a base model controller
class BaseModelController {
    protected static $model = '';
}
```

#### What I want

What I want to do now is to have basic functionality in both base controller and base model, for example adding the function `delete()` into the `BaseModelController`:

```
public static function delete($id) {
    $stmt = Database::prepare('DELETE FROM `' . $table . '` WHERE `id`=?');
    $res  = $stmt->execute(array($id));
}
```

#### The problem

How do I get the table name? Theoretically I am searching for something like the following:

```
$table = static::$model::$table;
```

But, unfortunately this does not work. **Is this even possible?**

Comment: What's the error? I'd guess it was something to do with the static keyword usage. Also, what version of PHP?

Comment: Support for this kind of shortcut should be added in the next versions of php, like `$class->method()->newMethod();`

Comment: Doing this is a violation of the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), as it would require an object to know about the internals of an object more than one neighbor away.  This is not good for long term maintainability and design, so I'd suggest re-factoring and restructuring your application to reduce the need to go across multiple classes...  In this particular example, you'd probably be better off with a data mapper...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save `static::$model` into a temporary variable:

```
$model = static::$model;
$table = $model::$table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you found a place to put your line that the protected visibility is not an issue:

```
$class = static::$model;
$table = $class::$table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ha! You're doing exactly the same thing I'm doing (a.k.a PHP Model system) (I'm doing it a different way, though :P) It's a pain in the *&#, just so you know.

i believe you could do `$class_name::$static_property` in PHP5.3 but not 2 levels